# Mac dvorak layout login issue

Tags: mac, login, dvorak

I'm facing a stupid issue with my mac ; yesterday I tried dvorak, so I set my macbook layout in, well, dvorak... And now I can't access it because I can't type my password...

Would anyone have the exact mac dvorak layout? My password is quite complicated and don't manage to type it successfully with the pictures I have found across the Internet...

Thanks a lot for your help!

Comment: Can you access a time machine backup from before the change? It's probably the easiest thing to do.

Answer (score 1):

[Here you go](http://www.chimoosoft.com/Images/dvorak/dvorak.jpg). This is an image of the Mac Dvorak layout.

Assuming that you used the basic (US) Dvorak layout, [this image should help](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:KB_United_States_Dvorak.svg). If you used a variant layout, please let us know. If you have an ISO (i.e, European) keyboard and you used US Dvorak, note that symbols on the numeric keys will be different than what you're used to.

Comment: I have already tried this one, but I actually need # * / $ : and ?

Comment: #, $ and * are the same (shift-3, shift-4 and shift-8, respectively). / corresponds to [ on a normal ANSI QWERTY keyboard (if you have an ISO (European) keyboard, it should be the same). : is shift-z. ? is the same key as /, with a shift (shift-[)

Comment: "#, $ and * are the same (shift-3, shift-4 and shift-8, respectively)": sorry, that assumes an ANSI keyboard. If you have a non-US keyboard, these will not match what you see on your keys. Nevertheless, the keypresses I listed are the correct ones (for US Dvorak).

Answer (score 1):

Screenshots of the Dvorak layout that comes with OS X:

[image]
[image]

The Users & Groups preference pane has an option to show the input menu on the login window. You can enable it in single user mode with `defaults write /Library/Preferences/com.apple.loginwindow.plist showInputMenu -bool true`.